# Web based query tool(similiar to oracle- sqldeveloper) for oracle can be used as web application

Tags: sql, oracle, web-applications, oracle-sqldeveloper

Maybe this question has been asked before but as far as i've checked the entries i've found two possible entries which are very old, so would like to start a new post around the discussion ?

Found this post on Google Code, but project is discontinued to make it available on web:

- [http://code.google.com/p/oracle-gui/](https://code.google.com/archive/p/oracle-gui/)
- https://code.google.com/archive/p/database-explorer/

I want to have your opinions and experience is there a any tool which can be deployable on server as a web application (i.e. nodejs, tomcat war application) that i can use similiar to sqldeveloper ?

SQLDeveloper for web is not fitting for me because i am not using Oracle on Cloud so i want a deployable tool which i can manage on my web application server.

Comment: I don't understand "off-topic" flag, i think that is relevant as there are similiar questions which is active currently on stackoverflow. You can check similiar old-posts asking same content from 2012-2013.

Answer (score 2):

If it is an Oracle database, it might already have **Oracle Application Express** (Apex) installed.

Apart from being a tool to develop applications (all you need is a browser), it also contains **SQL Workshop** which offers

- object browser
- data workshop
- query builder
- schema comparison tool
- lets you execute SQL commands and scripts
- etc.

So - have a look.

Comment: Thanks for your kind input, but as much as i've understood SQL workshop is also cloud based, my requirement is more in the way to host On-Premise application.

Comment: You're welcome. But, you **mis**understood it. Apex is (or *can be*) installed in your on-premise database.

Comment: oracletool.com - Old technology, it's written in Perl and uses DBD::Oracle but it still works. It's more DBA oriented than end user. Install in one place, use with all databases. I wrote it but don't really support it any more.

Answer (score 1):

SQL Developer Web will be available for you on-prem later this year via ORDS.

You'll be able to run it for your own local databases, versions 11gR2 and higher.

For free.

Comment: Hello again, where is this announcement existing, i could not find some hits regarding to this kind of information on google or web.

Comment: It's scheduled to be released with ORDS v19.3 - due in a couple of weeks, give or take.